# How to invoke a Eclipse Clean-Up Profile programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Is there a way to invoke a specific Clean-Up profile (Source->Clean Up) programmatically?

I would like to invoke it on an iterable of ICompilationUnits.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the declarations in `org.eclise.jdt.ui`.

The relevant command ID is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.clean.up` and the implementation is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.AllCleanUpsAction`. Unfortunately it is an internal action and the command does not support any parameters.

I can see three possible approaches:

- create an `AllCleanUpsAction` and invoke `...run(new StructuredSelection(<compilation units>[]))`. Problem: the action is internal so you might want to create a fragment to access it...
- open the package navigator view. Select the proper files corresponding to the compilation units. Execute the command ID via `IHandlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.clean.up")`. Problem: the package navigator is changed... and you might not have all compilation units in visible in the navigator.
- set the current selection in your view to `new StructuredSelection(<compilation units>[])`. Then execute the command as above. Problem: I'm not sure the command is properly enabled..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RefactoringExecutionStarter.startCleanupRefactoring` which takes an array of `ICompilationUnits` to perform the clean up on as one of its parameters. This method also allows you to specify the `ICleanUp`s that you want to perform and allows you to skip showing the clean up wizard if you want.

Here's an example which removes unnecessary parentheses:

```java
ICleanUp[] cleanUps = new ICleanUp[]{new ExpressionsCleanUp(){
    @Override
    protected boolean isEnabled(String key){
        switch(key){
        case CleanUpConstants.EXPRESSIONS_USE_PARENTHESES:
        case CleanUpConstants.EXPRESSIONS_USE_PARENTHESES_NEVER:
            return true;
        case CleanUpConstants.EXPRESSIONS_USE_PARENTHESES_ALWAYS:
            return false;
        default:
            return super.isEnabled(key);
        }
    }
}};
ICompilationUnit[] icus = new ICompilationUnit[]{icu};
Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event).getSite().getShell();
try {
    RefactoringExecutionStarter.startCleanupRefactoring(
            icus, cleanUps, false, shell, false, ActionMessages.CleanUpAction_actionName);
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```